# Creating grid with 2 axis

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to create a grid that contains Events on the x axis and Requirements on the y axis and is filled with solutions.

```
        Event1        Event2
Req1    Sol1
Req2                  Sol2
```

My Model contains a list of Events, which contains their related Requirements, which contain their related Solutions. Every Event can have 0 or more Requirements and each Requirement can have 0 or more solutions.

How can I accurately show this grid in razor?

Here is my attempt:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="span-6"></td>
        @foreach(var events in Model.Events)
        {
        <td colspan="3">
            @events.Name
        </td>
            requirementsList.AddRange(events.Requirements);
        }
    </tr>
    @foreach(var req in requirementsList)
    {   
        <tr>
            <td>
                @req.Name
            </td>
            <!--Insert logic to align solution with Event-->
            <td>
                @req.Solution
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Of course this is only showing all solutions in the first event column.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar thing in PHP for my timesheet system, I want hours worked for each employee on each day (between 2 dates):

```
       | 1 May | 2 May | ... May
Fred   | 6     |
George |       |  4    |
```

I used 3 foreach loops, first I outputted the dates, the I went rond each employee, and inside the employee loop, I looped round the dates again.

So for you it would be:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="span-6"></td>
        @foreach(var events in Model.Events)
        {
        <td colspan="3">
            @events.Name
        </td>
            requirementsList.AddRange(events.Requirements);
        }
    </tr>
    @foreach(var req in requirementsList)
    {   
        <tr>
            <td>
                @req.Name
            </td>
            @foreach(var events in Model.Events)
            {
                @curRec = events.Requirements
               @if (curRec.HasSolution) // If has a solution.
                // Very important so solutions can be aligned properly
               { // Output the solution
            <td>
                @curRec.Solution
            </td>
               } else { // Output a empty cell
                   <td></td>
               }
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```